# Pairing in Group Cohomology

Tags: cohomology, group-cohomology, notation, cup-product

I am following Ararat Babakhanian's Cohomological Methods in Group theory.

Let $A,B,C$ be $G$ modules then we have a $G$ module structre on $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(B,C)$ with $$\sigma.f(x)=\sigma(f\sigma^{-1}x)$$

$  A\times B\xrightarrow{\cdot } C$ is called a $G$ pairing if $\sigma a\cdot \sigma b=\sigma (a\cdot b)$ for all $\sigma\in G$ and $a\in A, b\in B$.

By Universal property of tensor products, this induces a unique linear map $\Omega : A\otimes B\rightarrow C$ such that $\Omega (a\otimes b)=a\cdot b$.

There is then a homomorphism of cohomology groups $H^{p+q}(G,A\otimes B)\xrightarrow{\Omega^*} H^{p+q}(G,C)$ induced from $\Omega : A\otimes B\rightarrow C$.

We have cup product map $H^p(G,A)\times H^q(G,B)\xrightarrow{\cup} H^{p+q}(G,A\otimes B)$, composing with $\Omega^*$ we have the map 
$$H^p(G,A)\times H^q(G,B)\rightarrow H^{p+q}(G,C)$$

He then says we have evaluation (Bilinear) map $$\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(B,C)\times B\rightarrow C$$

with $(f,b)\mapsto f(b)$. I checked that this is a $G$ pairing.

In this case we should get map

$$H^p(G,\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(B,C) )\times H^q(G,B)\rightarrow H^{p+q}(G,C)$$

But then, he writes there is a map

$$H^p(G,\text{Hom}(B,C) )\times H^q(G,B)\rightarrow H^{p+q}(G,C)$$

Where $\text{Hom}(B,C)$ denote all $G$ module homomorphisms..

So, what happened here? Though We can  restrict evaluation mp to $\text{Hom}(B,C)$, there is no module strutre on this, so we can not talk about cohomology or anything..

This continued in further material.. Let me know what is the point here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have not read Babakhanian, so I am only guessing. But could it be that he meant that there is a $G$-map $\mbox{Hom}(B,C) \to \mbox{Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(B,C)$ and this is what induces the pairing? Here $Hom(B,C)$ is considered a $G$-module with the trivial action, and the map is inclusion of fixed points.

Comment: It can be that.. I am not sure @GregoryArone

Comment: This just sounds like a typo in the book. (Which can very well get repeated over and over -- authors often write formulas by copypasting.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg : I would be happy if that is the case.... How much sure are you about this?

Comment: By definition,  ${\rm Hom}(B,C)$ is the submodule of ${\rm Hom}_{\mathbb Z}(B,C)$ on which $G$ acts trivially, so there *is* a $G$-module structure on it, the trivial one. So your interpretation via restriction does make sense, but a typo still seems more likely. It is actually much more common to write ${\rm Hom}$ for all $\mathbb{Z}$-linear homs, and ${\rm Hom}_G$ for $G$-homs.

Comment: @AlexB. : Ok. For time being i assume it is a typo... If there is any serious result in next chapters that depends on this heavily I would ask here.. By your website, you seem to be working on number theory.. Can you suggest some notes about cup products...

Comment: Among number theorists, a canonical reference is the chapter of Atiyah-Wall on group cohomology in Cassels-Fröhlich. Another good reference is Ken Brown's book "Cohomology of Groups".

Comment: @AlexB. : Thank you.. I will read that..